# MIDI Playback with Per-Channel Soundfonts - Python

Tags: python, audio, midi, fluidsynth, soundfont

I'm working on a project for the first time with MIDI, and am wondering how I can play back a MIDI file setting soundfonts PER-CHANNEL.

I have something like this in Python so far using `pyFluidSynth`

```py
import fluidsynth
import time

midi_filename = './midi/file.mid'

piano_filename = './soundfount/piano.sf2'
bass_filename = './soundfount/bass.sf2'

fs = fluidsynth.Synth(samplerate=44100.0)
fs.start(driver='coreaudio')
piano_sf = fs.sfload(sf_filename)
bass_sf = fs.sfload(mine_sf)
fs.program_select(0, piano_sf, 0, 0)
fs.program_select(1, bass_sf, 0, 1)

fs.play_midi_file(midi_filename)
time.sleep(20)

fs.delete()
```

This plays the audio fine, but it seems to only be using `bass_sf`, that is, it overrides my initial assignment of `piano_sf`. I thought that since `program_select()` accepts a channel parameter that this would be the way, but it doesn't seem to work that way. I also tried a multi-soundfont bank and tried setting the bank / preset to different numbers and it still doesn't do anything. My device is an M1 Macbook and my project is Python 3.9.16.

I'm not married to `pyFluidSynth`, so if anyone knows any other ways that could be helpful. `mido` seemed like a dead end in terms of not being able to change instruments.

Thanks for the help in advance!